# glob: Alternate between variable and literal with glob_braces

Tags: php, glob

I can make `glob` work with glob_brace as long as all options in the alternation are normal strings.

```
glob("./path/*{foo,bar}*.txt", GLOB_BRACE)
```

However, neither of these three syntaxes will work:

```
$var = "bar";
glob("./path/*{foo,$var}*.txt", GLOB_BRACE)
glob("./path/*{foo,{$var}}*.txt", GLOB_BRACE)
glob("./path/*{foo,".$var."}*.txt", GLOB_BRACE)
```

Any ideas? Is this possible at all to use a variable as one of the options in the alternation?

Cheers, Manuel

Comment: tried: `glob("./path/*{foo,".$var."}*.txt", GLOB_BRACE)`

Comment: I found the issue. The problem is in the content of $var, not in the glob syntax.

My third option (the one you suggested) seems to work. Thanks, Dagon.